# writing custom test reporter with serenity bdd

Tags: serenity-bdd, reporters, test-reporting

I want to write a custom reporter for serenity. I wrote a class that implements AcceptanceTestReporter interface and overrode some of the methods but I dont see this reporter getting executed. Can anyone list the steps needed to write and register a custom reporter with serenity?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing reporter interface alone won't work, You have to register a new Thucydides listener by implementing the StepListener interface and placing your class in the classpath. Serenity will automatically detect the listener and add it to the registered listeners. It will load custom listeners automatically when a test starts for the first time.  For more details please look into below post

https://schenkweb.nl/2017/07/11/serenity-bdd-register-a-custom-listener/

Comment: My question is about registering a reporter. Customer listener I have already implemented.

Comment: If you follow the link provided above it was clearly given how to to register a custom listner                                                                                                                       
    in the resources folder of the project you are using create a directory META-INF within the META-INF directory create a new directory services
    now create a new file in the services directory with the name net.thucydides.core.steps.StepListener open the newly created file and add the class you created earlier with its fully qualified name eg. nl.detesters.MyCustomListener

Comment: web archive to the rescue - see https://web.archive.org/web/20201029065652/https://schenkweb.nl/2017/07/11/serenity-bdd-register-a-custom-listener/